# Sprite not showing renderToTexture Map / rendertarget map

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am working with three.js and I set up a second scene and camera and added a cylinder to it. Now I setup a rendertarget and I wanted to show this renderedScene on a sprite (HUD-Sprite so to say), but the sprite is not showing up. I added a plane into the original scene and it shows the rendertarget perfectly fine.

What I already checked:

1) 
When using the rtTexture as a map for a MeshLambertMaterial, it works perfectly fine

2) 
When loading an image for the sprite with *ImageUtils* and using this as a map for the SpriteMaterial, it works great and the spline is showing up where it should be!

I have the feeling that I overlooked something. 
Would be cool if someone can help me.

OK, guys, i created a jsFiddle, maybe this helps!

[My Fiddle for RenderTarget Sprite Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Pk85y/38/)

as you can see there, the rendertarget is correctly display on the plane and there is a sprite with screenspace coordinates in there but it does not show the renderTarget.

```
rttMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000, map: rtTexture, 
                                         alignment: THREE.SpriteAlignment.topLeft,
                                         useScreenCoordinates: true}  );
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Took me a while, but managed to get the `Sprite` to show up just with a simple map. http://jsfiddle.net/Pk85y/40/ Using a RTT texture on a `Sprite` may be not supported though. I think you should post it as a feature request on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go behind-the-back of `WebGLRenderer` to do this, as it is not supported.

```
sprite.material.map.__webglTexture = rtTexture.__webglTexture;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pk85y/47/

three.js r.61

Comment: Cool, thank you very much for your answer! So, as you have more insight than me: Why is it that the cylinder in the rendertarget is pure red? Is the MeshNormal-Shader not processed at this point in the render-process? Anyway, thanks for this at all. Maybe there can be a PR in the future to support this kind of stuff, anyway,great! :)

Comment: Lol, TRUE!!! Did not see that, quite interesting. :) West, thank you very very much for your efforts! Keep contributing to Three.js :)